# how to assign each of multiple lines in a file as different variable?

Tags: bash

this is probably a very simple question. I looked at other answers but couldn't come up with a solution. I have a 365 line date file. file as below,

```
01-01-2000
02-01-2000
```

I need to read this file line by line and assign each day to a separate variable. like this,

```
d001=01-01-2000
d002=02-01-2000
```

I tried while read commands but couldn't get them to work.It takes a lot of time to shoot one by one. How can I do it quickly?

Comment: You probably need an array (or to operate directly on each line) rather than 365 variables. What are you planning to do with the data ?

Comment: You probably want to use arrays, not create variables with names known at run-time.

Comment: I need to use it in different places at different times, so I need to assign it to different variables.

Comment: What do those two things have to do with each other? How can you use a separate set of variables "in different places at different times" where you can't also use individual elements of an array the same way?

Comment: After all, array element 0 is `d[0]`; you assign to it with `d[0]=...`, look it up with `"${d[0]}"` -- this parallels `d0=` and `${d0}` for lookup and assignment of a normal variable.

Comment: let's assume you've created 365 variables named `d001`, `d002` ... `d365` ... how exactly does your code manage this list of variables? do you have these 365 variables hardcoded throughout your code? do you use indirect variable references? do you use namerefs? if you answer 'yes' to any of these ... I'm guessing you'll find an array much easier to use than any of these other methods of managing 365 separate variables

Comment: This is an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You're asking about how to implement what you think is the solution to a problem rather than asking how to solve a problem.

Comment: Here's one way to get what you requested: `for i in {001..999}; do read -r "d$i" || break; done <dates.txt`.  However, as others have pointed out, that is almost certainly not the best way to do whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to create named variable out of an associative array, is time waste and not supported *de-facto*. Better use this, using an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array

while read -r line; do
    printf -v key 'd%03d' $((++c))
    array[$key]=$line
done < file
```

### Output

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do echo "key=$i value=${array[$i]}"; done
key=d001 value=01-01-2000
key=d002 value=02-01-2000
```

Comment: Is there concrete benefit to using an associative array with padded keys, vs a numerically-indexed array without the padding?

Comment: It's how OP asked the question @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- an array is acceptable
- array index should start with 1

Sample input:

```
$ cat sample.dat
01-01-2000
02-01-2000
03-01-2000
04-01-2000
05-01-2000
```

One `bash/mapfile` option:

```
unset d                             # make sure variable is not currently in use
mapfile -t -O1 d < sample.dat       # load each line from file into separate array location
```

This generates:

```
$ typeset -p d
declare -a d=([1]="01-01-2000" [2]="02-01-2000" [3]="03-01-2000" [4]="04-01-2000" [5]="05-01-2000")

$ for i in "${!d[@]}"; do echo "d[$i] = ${d[i]}"; done
d[1] = 01-01-2000
d[2] = 02-01-2000
d[3] = 03-01-2000
d[4] = 04-01-2000
d[5] = 05-01-2000
```

In OP's code, references to `$d001` now become `${d[1]}`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick one-liner would be:

`eval $(awk 'BEGIN{cnt=0}{printf "d%3.3d=\"%s\"\n",cnt,$0; cnt++}' your_file)`

`eval` makes the shell variables known inside your script or shell. Use `echo $d000` to show the first one of the newly defined variables. There should be no shell special characters (like * and $) inside `your_file`. Remove `eval $()` to see the result of the `awk` command. The `\"` quoted `%s` is to allow spaces in the variable values. If you don't have any spaces in `your_file` you can remove the `\"` before and after `%s`.